# Ruby sub-oject with dynamics presence of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I quite new ruby (rails) developer and I need to interface a complex object behavior. I'll try to explain as much as I can.

I've an object A in which I would like to contains an array of entities(B) which have a boolean base and a type. If this boolean is true some other properties can be set (and input fields can be showed in dashboard).

I don't really want to create a separate object(B).

I know I could use `Struct.new(..)`but don't know if it's usable.

By the way the array of B entities could be initialized when creating A object depends on A params and B type.

So my questions are:

- Is it better to use a separate object or a `Struct.new(...)`entities for B ?
- How could I manage other B params depends on type?

I hope it's understandable.

Thanks

Comment: Everything in ruby is a object. So B will be a separate object no matter what you do. Or did you mean that you don't want to create a class for B?

Comment: Yes I don't really want to create a class for B because I have no need to manage instancies by there own outside A object

Comment: I would model this with an ActiveRecord association between objects A and B. Associations can make it easier for A to manage B depending on your use case. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Reconsider your motivation to avoid creating a class / module. Sure you can always use Struct instead of a class / module but what benefit is that really bringing? Classes are a good way to organize your code, and by avoiding them you're probably making things more difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will create these classes in aim to manage them all specifically Thanks all !